# My.Computer.fileSystem.moveFile:The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net

***My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(strFile, desti)

above is the code that I use to move file from "strFile" to "desti".when I move a Textfile which content text is work fine, the problem occur when I going to move a file that is empty content. I guess is something like open file stream and close file stream,but I not sure about this, is anyone can help? thanks.

****Edit**

strFile = INIRead(gSysFile, "MAIN", table(x), "")

Comment: Probably it is your own process that keeps the file open. You should check if you have some open stream around. Show the code that writes/creates the `strFile`

Comment: @Steve i already edit the question, the steFile basically is just a file path.

Comment: So the method that returns your file is INIRead, what is the code of it? Does it open the file? If yes, does it close after?. Please add the code of that method.

Comment: i got it, is one of the stream reader i left it open causing the problem. Anyway Thanks for Trying to help!